# Stop box from moving if it hits another box

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to code a GUI that allows the user to move a box around. There is also another box on the screen, called "block" that the box isn't allowed to intersect. I have box moving fine, but I don't know how to stop the two from intersecting and keep the drawing of the box on the screen. Right now, the box disappear when it hits the block (I know why it's doing this, I just don't know how to fix it).

X and Y are the movement detected by the left and right mouse keys.

```
box = new Rectangle2D.Double(0 + X, 0 + Y, 200, 50);
block = new Rectangle2D.Double(300, 300, 50, 50);

if (box.intersects(block)) {
        hit = true;

    } else {
        hit = false;
    }    

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2.draw(block);
    if (model.hit()) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.drawString("WHOA THERE", 20, 50);
    } else {
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2.fill(box);
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on how the box is moved? What you should do is detect the intersection when you try to update the position of the box, not when it's drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what you're asking. If you're asking how to draw the box when it hits the block, the problem is your if/else statement. In the if case, it skips the drawing block. Remove the else to draw the box even if it hits.

If you're asking how to prevent the two boxes from intersecting, that's easy. If you detect they intersect, move the moving box so it's just outside the block. So if the block is at x = 10, set the moving box (`model`?) so it's at x = 11. HTH

Comment: My problem with that is it prints the warning message "WHOA THERE" but then continues to let the box pass through the block.

Comment: When you get the updated position of the box, look for intersection with the block. If it intersects, set the position of box so it's not intersecting the block.

Comment: If this isn't clear, post your KeyListener, and I can show you actual code.